# RPA Express (WorkFussion) "No modal dialog is currently open" on second iteration, after "OK" click in modal dialog

Tags: selenium, modal-dialog, rpa, workfusion

My RPA Express project iterates through a number of URLs and if a certain condition is met, clicks on a icon that pops up a HTML "Confirm" modal dialog. The code clicks "OK" (tried also Keypress "Enter") and then goes into a next URL. 
The problem is that after the first confirmation (click OK or press Enter) on the dialog box and processing to a next URL, all attempts to use Web Element (get by xpath) fail with:

**Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: No modal dialog is currently open**

I tried unsuccessfully:

- to "CTRL+F5" the page on reload
- set focus on the page (with MouseClick) after reload

It looks like the system does not recognize that the modal dialog was actually closed.
Any idea how to get it fixed?

Here is the main loop code:

```
event_id_list.each( {this_event_id ->
this_id = RString.of(RNumber.fromRepresentation("${this_event_id}","0;pl-PL").toRepresentation("0;pl-PL"))
this_url = event_url_patern.replaceFirstIgnoreCase("[id]", "${this_id}")
confirm_close_window = RBoolean.fromCanonical("false")

sleep(1000)

inDesktop {
    sendKeys(StringTransformations.getKeyPressText(63, 0, 116, 2))
}
// Group of actions: Open Event URL
$(byImage("1536237127355-anchor-1536911026524.apng", Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0))).click()
setClipboardText(this_url as String)

inDesktop {
    sendKeys(StringTransformations.getHotKeyText(97, 2))
}

inDesktop {
    sendKeys(StringTransformations.getHotKeyText(118, 2))
}

inDesktop {
    sendKeys(StringTransformations.getKeyPressText(28, 13, 10, 0))
}

def i1 = System.currentTimeMillis() + 8000

boolean i0 = true

while (i0) {
    try {
        $(byImage("1536912304113-anchor.apng")).getCoordinates()
        even_opened = RBoolean.TRUE
        break
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        even_opened = RBoolean.FALSE
    }
    i0 = System.currentTimeMillis() < i1
}




$(byImage("1537167271142-anchor-1537167271149.apng", Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0))).click()

try {


    this_crewx_vessel = RString.of($(byXpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/b")).text())

} catch (Exception i2) {

    this_crewx_vessel = RString.of("N/A")

}
try {


    this_crewx_port = RString.of($(byXpath("//*[@id=\"form1\"]/div[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/b/a")).text())

} catch (Exception i3) {

    this_crewx_port = RString.of("N/A")

}
sleep(4000)
Resource.append("${log_file_path}", "<p>Processing  id ${this_id} (${this_crewx_vessel} at ${this_crewx_port}) - outcome: ", "UTF-8")



icon_src = RString.of($(byXpath("//*[@id=\"toggleEventImg\"]")).getAttribute("src"))

if ((RString.of("images/lock.gif")) in (icon_src)) {




    $(byXpath("//*[@id=\"toggleEventImg\"]")).click()





    def i5 = System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000

    boolean i4 = true

    while (i4) {
        try {
            $(byImage("1536910894370-anchor.apng")).getCoordinates()
            confirm_close_window = RBoolean.TRUE
            break
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            confirm_close_window = RBoolean.FALSE
        }
        i4 = System.currentTimeMillis() < i5
    }


    if ((confirm_close_window) == (RBoolean.fromCanonical('true'))) {

        inDesktop {
            sendKeys(StringTransformations.getKeyPressText(28, 13, 10, 0))
        }

        sleep(4000)
        Resource.append("${log_file_path}", "closed.</p>", "UTF-8")



        // compare_item = RString.of($(byXpath("//*[@id=\"toggleEventImg\"]")).text())
    } else {
        sleep(4000)
        Resource.append("${log_file_path}", "no action (confirm window no show)</p>", "UTF-8")

    }
} else {
    sleep(4000)
    Resource.append("${log_file_path}", "no action (already closed).</p>", "UTF-8")

}
})
```

The error is thrown at:

```
icon_src = RString.of($(byXpath("//*[@id=\"toggleEventImg\"]")).getAttribute("src"))
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trials

Comment: Code added as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking an image and typing in the url, try opening the URL using OpenIE or OpenChrome

```
openIE(UrlOperations.ensureProtocol("${this_url}"))
```

Comment: Thanks for  your advise.
Replaced the Open Evern URL group with

`openFirefox(UrlOperations.ensureProtocol("${this_url}"))`

but the outcome is the same ("No modal..." after first Confirm box appearing and getting to a next URL.

Comment: The updated code is under this [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/edi875zsm2ys7zk/code001.txt?dl=0